# View() in RStudio works but View() in R x64 doesn't?

Tags: r, listview

Let this be the arbitrary code:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- runif(100)
fit <- lm(y~x)
```

Using View(fit) in RStudio gives a list of variables. While View(fit) in the original R x64 console, v3.5.1, returns the error:
"Error in as.data.frame.default(x) :  cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame"

What is causing this?

Comment: Per the documentation,`View()` "[invokes] a spreadsheet-style data viewer on a matrix-like R object.". `lm()` does not return a matrix style object, however, RStudio extends the functionality to show you additional object properties.

Comment: RStudio is essentially showing you a combination of `str(fit)` and `summary(fit)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the viewer panel in RStudio is a bit more advanced than the little program that is launched from the regular R console. You could always try the `listviewer` package if you can't access RStudio but need this functionality.

```
library(listviewer)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- runif(100)
fit <- lm(y~x)
jsonedit(fit)
```